# How to know, from which class trigger is being called?

Tags: apex, trigger

I am in a situation, where I need to put some condition in trigger depends on the page from it being triggered/called. I tried with

```
Apexpages.currentPage().getUrl()
```

But it is giving NULL pointer exception.

So, is there any ways, so that I can change only in particular Trigger, irrespective of all invoking class.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You could put a flag on the record and then you can access it in the trigger

Comment: Yes agree with Mihai You need to use any flag when you are inserting/updating record from page Just make this flag to true else false from somewhere else.

Comment: I had idea of Flag, but I wanted a solution in trigger only, so that I don't have to touch/modify class.  Btw thanks for solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just declare a static variable in your trigger handler class

```
public static boolean flag= false;
```

Now from your custom class set this to true.

```
triggerhandler.flag = true;
```

Now you have total controller here. You can also pass some Id or other variable using this approach.